# Remove all special characters from string

Tags: c#, vb.net, postgresql

For example `tableA` contains two columns called `prodid` and `product`. `product`column consists of more than `100 rows` the rows may contain product names with some special characters like `* , ' [ ( ] ) #` etc.

I need to change this:

```
    prodid |    product   |
   --------|-----------   |
     1     | ab's cap60   |
     2     | hhmm*rect    |
```

to this:

```
    prodid |    product   |
   --------|-----------   |
     1     | abs cap60    |
     2     | hhmmrect     |
```

> Database : PostgreSQL

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  prodid, 
  regexp_replace(product, '[^\w\s]', '', 'g') product
FROM tableA
```

**Test**

```
SELECT regexp_replace('hello!@#$%^*()_,[]', '[^\w\s]', '', 'g')
//hello
```

Comment: does this remove `* , ' [ ( ] ) # ` ??

Comment: i tried exactly what you have answered but still product column contains name with `*` `,`

Comment: @hector I just tested it on postgres 9.3 and it removes `*` and `,` updated answer with test results